# How can I create a control like the one from Eclipse's autocomplete?

Tags: c#, .net, autocomplete, custom-controls, boo

I'd like to create an autocomplete control using Boo/C#. Here's a screenshot from the internet if you don't know how it looks like :

[alt text http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.5M7-200904302300/images/p2autocomplete.png](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.5M7-200904302300/images/p2autocomplete.png)

I'm basically thinking of a undecorated window/dialog ( which I'm not sure how would I implement ), or a control that can be displayed on it's own ( a ListBox of some sort ).

How could I implement such a control?

**I'm very interested in the popping-out part of the control!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like that a while back and did use a listbox to display the result.
All i needed to do was to monitor the KeyUp event to do the fetching of the data and display the listbox. I added the listbox as a hidden control  to the form and would show it when appropriate after setting its position

Comment: I haven't thought about this approach. Very interesting. What about creating an undecorated window. By undecorated I mean without the status bar, no minimize button, no maximize button, no close button. Can this be done?

Comment: That could actually work too i guess. Your form has a property call formBorderStyle. just set it to 'none'.

Comment: How have you handled the case when the text is at the bottom of the page? Did you display your list above it?

Comment: Yep. baiscally i check the size of the main window first and depending on how many items i think i am returning,i calulate the size of the listbox and display it either at the top or the bottom of the textbox. pretty much like the dropdownlist does it.
I have another tip if you would like to do it dropdownlist style: if you can debug microsoft code when a dropdownlist item is clicked, use Reflector.Net to take a look at what the do to show the dropdown result list

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `TextBox` already does auto completion. See [`TextBox.AutoCompleteSource` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource.aspx).